# Error in App clips Domain status and advanced app clip experience

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-appclips

I have to add App Clip functionality when I scan an NFC tag.
I have created an AASA file and hosted it on the server. My AASA file is valid JSON.

```
{
    "applinks":{
    "apps":[],
    "details":[
    {
    "appID":"123456789.com.appname",
    "paths":[
    "*"
    ]
    }
    ]
    },
    "appclips":{
    "apps":[
    "123456789.com.appname.Clip"
    ]
    }
    }
```

However, when I upload the build on AppStore, it gives me an error stating "1 invalid domain".
When I view its status, it shows "Insecure redirects forbidden" in the Cache status and domain status.

Also, If I go to make an app clip experience on App Store and type the url, I always get this error:
"This URL is not contained in your app’s associated domains. Update associated domains or use a different URL."

Please guide me on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may be able to help with the first issue. I am also seeing the second error message in App Store Connect. I have an open TSI ticket with Apple and I'll post here if I'm able to resolve it.

For the first issue...

What do you see if you run this in the command line?

```
curl -v https://your_domain.com/apple-app-site-association
```

If you're serving that file from the `.well-known` directory, then just use that in the URL instead. Two things to check with curl:

1. Make sure the `content-type` header is `application/json` and not plain text or something else. If you're not serving it over https, you need to sign that file cryptographically and the content-type needs to be something else.
2. Do you see any redirects? Maybe you're going from HTTPS to an HTTP redirect? That could be it.

Comment: I re-checked as per your suggestion.
1. If I check my AASA file through the AASA file validator, it shows me that my AASA file is valid and the content-type is application/json. However, if I do this using the curl command mentioned above, I get text/html as content-type.

2. There aren't any redirects.

Comment: Gotcha, this has happened to me before and I'm pretty sure it won't work with `text/html`

Comment: I tried all possible ways to set the content-type to application/json. I am using nginx configuration and tried this code : 

server {
   ...
   location /apple-app-site-association {
      default_type application/application/json;
   }
}

I tried to forcefully set the content-type to application/json but the curl command still gives the content-type as text/html. 
Can you please help me out with this ? Please let me know how did you set the content-type of the apple-app-site-association file.
Thanks!

Comment: This depends heavily on what you're using to serve up static files. I recommend asking a separate question tagged with that technology (e.g. nginx)